# How to change file extension sitemap.php to sitemap.xml using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

If I write URL domain.com/something-any-word website is running properly. But I need a sitemap in XML format so I write PHP code in sitemap.php. I want in runtime sitemap.xml (ref. website is https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/make-dynamic-xml-sitemap-in-php-script.html)

my current .htaccess file is working without sitemap.xml

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Could you include a little more detail about what you mean when you say your .htaccess file is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sitemap.php to runtime show sitemap.xml and you want yourdomain.com/something-without-ext write this code in .htacces file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the request to that sitemap as you like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine ^/?sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap.php [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

To change the file extension from `sitemap.php` to `sitemap.xml` using an `.htaccess` file, you can use Apache's mod_rewrite module to rewrite the URL. Here's a step-by-step guide with the necessary code:

1. Create or edit the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your website if it doesn't already exist.
2. Make sure that your server has mod_rewrite enabled. You can usually enable it by uncommenting the following line in your Apache configuration file (`httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`):

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```

   Once you've made changes to your Apache configuration, you'll need to restart Apache to apply them.
3. In your `.htaccess` file, add the following code to rewrite requests for `sitemap.xml` to `sitemap.php`:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
   ```

   This code activates the `RewriteEngine`, which enables URL rewriting, and then uses the `RewriteRule` directive to match requests for `sitemap.xml` and internally rewrite them to `sitemap.php`.
4. Save the `.htaccess` file.
5. Now, when a user requests `http://yourwebsite.com/sitemap.xml`, Apache will internally process `sitemap.php` while displaying `sitemap.xml` in the URL.